# Nav bar is cut off in Google Chrome

Tags: css

I am stumped. When I view my temp. file in Firefox it displays the full Nav Bar but when I view in 
Google Chrome it cuts off the end of the "Contact" button. I have spent so much time trying to fix 
this to no avail....I have also tried Firebug with no luck.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I am very new at this so would appreciate any input...

[link to site](http://360webmedia.com/indexjuly9.html)

Comment: If you read the FAQ it says please don't put links to external sites saying: "See here" because it most likely will be gone in a few weeks and will leave a worthless artifact hanging around that lessens the value of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Taking out the width seems to fix it.

```
.menuCntr .right {
    width: 630px; <- remove that
```

Comment: @Peter - I tried your suggestion but I still cannot see the full "contact" button in Google Chrome - I see part of the button but the entire text is missing...looks okay in Firefox.